# Infering course given origin and destination coordinates

Tags: gps, coordinates, bearing

I have two points. A vehicle is at point A and I have the coordinates at point A. The vehicle moves to point B and I know the coordinates as well.

I would like to find the angle of movement i.e., 0,180,90,45,360 degrees etc. With the angle, I can tell in what direction its headed relative to origin.

Given that I know the coordinates at A and B, how would I calculate the degree between point A and B.

Comment: I am not using any program. I am reading this https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/ to calculate bearing and i want to test with real data and see whether the formulas work.

Comment: See this link for more help. https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/

Comment: This is more than a little complicated, with the formal name of the [Inverse Geodetic Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems)

Comment: Add "bearing" to your question tags

Answer (score 1):

Do like sailors did in the past: take a mercator map that has the two locations on it, draw a straight line between the two points and measure using a protractor the angle with a meridian, that angle is your bearing.

You already found the link to maths and software
https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/